# android listview with multiple listitems per row

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to display multiple listitems per row in the listview.
The displaying is no problem, because I override getView and getCount.
But the problem lies in the onItemClickListener: I can't seem to be able to distinguish between which listitem is clicked.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Curious: Why not use a gridview to accomplish the same thing, yet you retain the ability to distinguish between different items when clicking?

Comment: you set onclicklistener on row.

Comment: with an onClicklistener you only get one position back and not left or right item so that's out of the question.
Ah, I didn't know the gridview component, but it seems interesting as it also uses an adapter
If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dymmeh I've learned about the GridView-component, which does exactly what I wanted!
Thanks @dymmeh

Answer (score 0):

In order to distinguish between which listitem is clicked, you can provide the click listener of that item in getView() method of an adapter.

Comment: that way I'll might end up creating hundreds of clicklisteners, no the only correct solution was the one from @dymmeh suggesting a GridView, It's meant for it